# Integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{c(\theta)}{(1 + x^2)^\theta} dx $

Tags: integration

I want to calculate this integral:$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{c(\theta)}{(1 + x^2)^\theta} dx $

it's easy to do, when $\theta$ is given: For example when $\theta$ is 1, then integral is equal to $\pi$

But how to calulate integral, when \theta is not given?

And $c(\theta)$ is a constant, that is dependent on $\theta $

Comment: what is $c(\theta)$?

Comment: @GuyFsone I added the description.

Comment: @DanielYefimov Take $c(\theta)$ out of $\int$ sign as a multiplier. It has no connect with $x$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{c(\theta)}{(1 + x^2)^\theta} dx = 2c(\theta)\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1 + x^2)^\theta} dx \\= c(\theta)\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{u^{1/2-1}}{(1 + u)^\theta} du =c(\theta)B(\frac{1}{2},\theta-\frac{1}{2})\\=c(\theta)\frac{\Gamma(1/2)\Gamma(\theta-1/2)}{\Gamma(\theta)}= c(\theta)\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(\theta-1/2)}{\Gamma(\theta)}$$
with $\Gamma(1/2) =\sqrt\pi$ and Where we used [the beta function](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonction_b%C3%AAta) and [Gammma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)

Comment: why does the $c(\theta)$ disappear then re-appear?

Comment: Where is that I  have edited . it has noting to do with problem at hand

Comment: It was a false equality, of course it has something to do with the problem haha. But yes, you've edited it in now so it's ok now.